# Abrir formulario automaticamente al abrir powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

estoy tratando de abrir un formulario de forma automática al abrir powerpoint pero no logro realizarlo.

Adjunto codigo:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Load userform1
    userform1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: No estás usando el evento correcto. Por cierto, si no vas continuar con tu pregunta anterior, al menos avisa.

Comment: Gracias, disculpa no lo había visto. Cómo podemos seguir esa conversación?

Comment: Power Point no tiene eventos de manera predeterminada, se tienen que activar a través del uso de Módulos de Clase, es el único modo.

Comment: Tienes alguna referencia donde buscar más info porfavor

Answer (score 0):

1. Debes crear un Módulo de Clase; a dicho módulo colócale de nombre "EventClassModule" y agrega lo siguiente a dicho módulo:

```
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_SlideShowBegin(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Evidentemente donde yo coloco "UserForm1" tú debes colocar el nombre del tuyo.

2. Inserta ahora un módulo estándar y agrégale el siguiente código:

```
Dim X As New EventClassModule

Sub InitializeApp()
    Set X.App = Application
End Sub
```

3. Corre la macro "InitializeApp", no verás que ocurra algo, pero eso es normal.
4. Si hiciste todo bien, ahora al poner tus diapositivas en modo de presentación, el Userform debería activarse.

Comentas.